# "Maximum update depth exceeded" error in react and react-cookie

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-cookie

I implemented a simple Login Form in React with Redux following this tutorial: https://jslancer.com/blog/2017/04/27/a-simple-login-flow-with-react-and-redux/

Everything works, but when I add cookies I get the error:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state.

and also:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can
>   happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside
>   componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of
>   nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I did some debugging and if I remove `onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})}` from the inputs in the code below the error disappears.

Any ideas why the following code is not working?

````
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie'

class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    let {username, password} = this.state;
    let { cookies, allCookies, isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError} = this.props;
    cookies.set('username', 'Ross', { path: '/', secure: true, httpOnly: true});
    console.log(cookies.get('username'));
    return (
      <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group-collection">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})} value={username}/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} value={password}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
    isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
    loginError: state.loginError,
  };
}

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(LoginForm));```
````

Comment: Have you tried using `connect(mapStateToProps)(withCookies(LoginForm))`?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya Tried now, same error...

Comment: My guess is that because your component it connected to the cookies HoC and then you are calling `cookies.set` in the `render` method, it is updating itself every time, creating an infinite loop.

Please try moving `cookies.set` to `componentDidMount`

Comment: @FernandoMontoya This solved my problem, thanks! :) Can you post as answer so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that because your component it connected to the cookies HoC and then you are calling `cookies.set` in the `render` method, it is updating itself every time, creating an infinite loop. Please try moving `cookies.set` to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Removing ```cookies.set``` from the ```render``` method solved this problem!